WPF on .net 4.8 has no useful stacktrace
The company I work at has an old WPF .net 4.8 desktop app running in production.
They are using log4net > application insights to log the errors. The errors are all there but some stacktraces seem not useful at all. What should I do so I get better stacktraces:
System.NullReferenceException:
   at MS.Internal.Controls.TemplatedAdorner.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore (PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler (PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall (WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen (WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

How would I find the location of such a stacktrace
I checked if innerexceptions contained any usefull information but there was also nothing usefull.

There is no full stack trace without the PDB files. You have to check the build settings of your application (or your projects) and enable it to deploy the PDB files. The PDB files basically map your source code to the compiled application. They are required to produce a complete source code related stack trace. And your stacktrace looks like this mapping is missing.

From the trace, it looks like it is recursing during a "layout" (Loading) step; trying to format a Grid cell. It shouldn't take that many "measures".  There may be no "user code" before the loading to trace.
